# Usage of RemoteCache with DeltaAware and Delta interface infinispan

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, distributed, infinispan, delta

I need some guidance related to the following scenario in infinispan. Here is my scenario:

1) I created two nodes and started successfully in infinispan using client server mode.

2) In the hot rod client I created a remotechachemanager and then obtained a RemoteCache.

3) In the remote cache I put like this cache.put(key, new HashMap()); it is successfully added.

4) Now when I am going to clear this value using cache.remove(key) , I am seeing that it is not getting removed and the hash map is still there every time I go to remove it.

How can clear the value so that it will be cleared from all node of the cluster?

How can I also propagate the changes like adding or removing from the value HashMap above?

Has it anything to do with implementing DeltaAware and Delta interface?

Please suggest me about this concept or some pointers where I can learn

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Removal of the HashMap should work as long as you use the same key and have equals() and hashCode() correctly implemented on the key. I assume you're using distributed or replicated mode.
**EDIT:** I've realized that equals() and hashCode() are not that important for RemoteCache, since the key is serialized anyway and all the comparison will be executed on the underlying byte[].

Remote cache does not directly support DeltaAware. Generally, using these is quite tricky even in library mode.

If you want to use cache with maps, I suggest rather using composite key like cache-key#map-key than storing complex HashMap.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes I am using distribute cache only. Sure I will implement the equals() and hashcode() and check. Besides using a hashMap as a value would have organized the data properly. but considering your comment, I think I will follow as you said and see. Another note is I tried to use AtomicHashMap as value as well, but it threw SerializationException when I tried to put in the cache.

Comment: One more observation Flavius. Actually..I was doing the removal after checking whether the cache contains the key or not. It was always giving the true and then I was removing. So it looks like the removal is not propagated to the cluster. I was not using this inside any transaction scope. Is this needed ?

Comment: No, transactions are not supported on client side. And as for using AtomicHashMap - this is a class from infinispan-core module. Infinispan-client-hotrod module does not depend on that and generally does not use it - it uses only infinispan-commons module. Therefore, don't try to use anything from infinispan-core in client-server mode.
I guess this is more complicated to distinguish if you're using some uberjar and not Maven with dependency management.

Comment: Your suggestion is well received Flavius. Thank you very much. I will change my approach then towards storing key, value only in the RemoteCache instead of HashMap.